# local variable 'pts' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function, variables, jupyter-notebook

i'm writing the following function:

```
def model(image):
  texts,points =text_extractor(image)
  pts=points[0]
  pt1,pt2,pt3=pts[0],pts[1],pts[2]
  return pt1,pt2,pt3
```

however the above code is giving the error:

```
     18     texts,points =text_extractor(image)
     19     pts=points[0]
---> 20     pt1,pt2,pt3=pts[0],pts[1],pts[2]
     21     image=skew_correction(image,(pt1,pt2,pt3))

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pts' referenced before assignment
```

i cant understand why this is arising as the variable 'pts' is already defined in line 19.

when i am separately running the snippet separately in a separate cell, the code is working properly and doing as expected. can anyone tell what is going wrong here. also when i am printing the value of variable 'pts' in the function like this:

```
def model(image):
  texts,points =text_extractor(image)
  pts=points[0]
  print(pts)
  pt1,pt2,pt3=pts[0],pts[1],pts[2]
  return pt1,pt2,pt3
```

corresponding output:

```
[[211 482]
 [242 479]
 [260 668]
 [230 671]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-ac65bafa631e> in <module>()
----> 1 model(im)

1 frames
<ipython-input-27-0a3790f540d2> in model(image)
     17     texts,points =text_extractor(image)
     18     pts=points[0]
---> 19     print(pts)
     20     pt1,pt2,pt3=pts[0],pts[1],pts[2]

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pts' referenced before assignment
```

this means the value of 'pts' is being printed correctly but at the same time it is being shown as unassigned.
why is this happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like points[0] are not assigned to pts.

just check what 'points' is from text_extractor().

Comment: i think points[0] are being correctly assigned to pts...the text_extractor() is a custom function and it is working fine. Also the same code is working fine when run outside the function, as a separate cell, as i also mentioned in the post